# Load data in memory during server startup in Django app

Tags: django, caching, redis, memcached

I am creating a Django app wherein I need to load and keep some data in memory when the server starts for quick access. To achieve this I am using Django's AppConfig class. The code looks something like this :

```
from django.core.cache import cache
class myAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp'
     def ready(self):
        data = myModel.objects.values('A','B','C') 
        cache.set('mykey', data)
```

The problem is that this data in cache will expire after sometime. One alternative is to increase the TIMEOUT value. But I want this to be available in memory all the time. Is there some other configuration or approach which I can use to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Redis. It does provide persistent data capture.

Check it out in https://redis.io/topics/persistence

You have to set it up by Redis Configuration.
There will be two methods to keep the data persist in the cache after reboot - both of them will save the data in other formats in HDD. I will suggest you set up the AOF for your purpose since it will record every write operation. However, it will cause more space.

Comment: would that be different from memcached ?

Comment: Memcached is a different software for memory caching. 
There are many comparison articles between them. 
As I have known, Memcached is a simple key-value storage, which the configurations are also simple comparing with Redis.  So, I don't think it has original snapshot and persistence functions.

On the other hand, Redis has more functions for storing data, such as partition, clustering, and persistence- suitable for a larger distributed system.

Answer (score 0):

The cache timeout argument can be set to None so that it never expires.

```
cache.set('mykey', data, timeout=None)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/cache/#cache-arguments